# Access Control Allow Origin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, safari, asp.net-web-api

I am writing my first WebAPI service, to be called from a pure HTML/javascript application.  I am starting visual studio first, then running my app in Safari ( it refuses to run in Chrome, and gives this exact error no matter what I do, but has been fine in Safari until now ).

Based on my other SO reading on this, I've added a header that is Access-Control-Allow-Origin with a value of *.

When I push the button in my web app, it makes an AJAX call and I can step through the debugger to see that it's calling my service fine.  When it returns, it always returns an object, and the error in Safari in the console is "XMLHttpRequest cannot load (myurl).  Origin file :// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

Any suggestions for how to get Safari to accept the return value would be greatly appreciated.  As I said, it's returning a class, which I expected WebAPI would turn in to a JSON string to return to the browser.  I don't know if I'm doing something wrong here, or if something is wrong in Safari.  I should mention, although I think it's obvious, I am using MVC4, ergo I am using Safari on Windows, not Mac.

Thanks

Comment: you can also go to the [Cross-domain Ajax with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) for more

Answer (score 0):

How are you currently adding the header? The problem isn't getting safari to accept the return value, your WebAPI is rejecting the request.

Here's an article on how to implement CORS in Web API v1 (MVC4). http://goo.gl/BZkrlf

If you can use MVC5/WebAPI v2, there is an easier way to enable CORS via a NuGet package (see this how-to http://goo.gl/60YkgX)

Comment: If my web api is rejecting the request, why can I step through the code ? How does it reject the request AFTER running my code ?

Comment: OK, looks like that article now only works with VS2013 as well, so I may as well try the NuGet package.  But I still don't get why it's making the call, running the code, THEN failing

Comment: Could you post the raw HTTP response from your WebAPI server here? It would be helpful to see everything that is coming back after the request.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with protocol mismatch. You cannot send a cross domain request to HTTP protocol if the request is originating from the FILE protocol. Try viewing the page using a local webserver so you can preview the page in the browser using HTTP. I have experienced this same issue - it is browser side and not a problem with your service.

Comment: OK - that makes some sort of sense, thank you, I will try that.

Comment: Sadly now it says Origin http://localhost:1323 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  Again, I can step through my code, the error comes when the code returns an object back to Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft.AspNet.Cors from nuget and adding

var attr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET");
 config.EnableCors(attr);

to WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors from nuget and adding